# Gradle is not picking up my Android Library

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to create a library/app project but it seems that Gradle doesn't want to find my Library Module.

***Folder hierarchy:***

```
<Project>
    app/
        build.gradle
        ...
    library/
        build.gradle
        ...
    build.gradle
    settings.gradle
```

***Gradle: Root settings.gradle***

```
    include ':app', ':library'
```

***Gradle: Root build.gradle***

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

***Gradle: Library build.gradle***

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
   ...
}
```

***Gradle: App build.gradle***

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    ...
}
dependencies {
    compile project(':library')
}
```

Library seems to compile and generate .AAR file but application won't compile due to "package .... does not exist" -> link to the library class

Comment: My library use this to be able to compile JNI code, that line is making not get the library as Dependency
    
    productFlavors {
        arm {
            ndk {
                abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "armeabi"
            }
        }
    }

Answer (score 2):

Fixed by removing this line on the Library module (My library module had to compile JNI)

```
productFlavors {
    arm {
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "armeabi"
        }
    }
}
```